# Delete outlet references when the control is deleted

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there anyway to automatically have XCode delete a property or variable when its corresponding control is deleted? For example say I create a button in XCode 4 within a view, then I assign it to a 'new referencing outlet' by doing that ctrl-click hijinks to the source code where I want the property to appear. But then I decide to delete the button. The property will still be in the source code. Why doesn't XCode delete the property?

Comment: perhaps that'll come in xcode 5. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess it's because deleting the property means deleting all code associated with that property. Xcode doesn't know if you've written some custom setter/getter methods, or if you have extensive amounts of code using that property throughout your project.

Sure, they could use the new fancy clang stuff to analyze your code and delete the property if it's not used anywhere, but I'm guessing that would be too much work.

Also, just because Xcode *can* generate the property for you, doesn't mean it actually did. In other words, if I created the property myself and hooked it up to the button in IB, do I really want Xcode to delete that code when I delete the button? Probably not.